# How does MLE helps to find the variance components of linear models?

Tags: variance, maximum-likelihood, linear-model

**How does MLE helps to find the variance components of linear models?
I understood how MLE/REML provides best parameters for my data but how does it find variance components of linear models?**

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the "variance components of linear models"?  The phrase is ambiguous.

Comment: yes by variance components i mean ...fixed and random effect of any linear models.

Comment: How would those differ from the "best parameters"?

Comment: if i have a mixed model y=Xa+Zg+e...how does REML finds best estimates of my variances. lets say estimates of Zg which here is random factor.